# Number sets symbols in Mathjax

Tags: support, mathjax

How can we write number sets symbols using Mathjax? For example what's the code for Natural numbers set? I couldn't find that in a vast of Mathjax help documents,and the only one I found doesn't work: \Natural or \mathds{N}

Comment: `\Bbb{N}`  gives $\Bbb{N}$ here. But at least the TeX system on my laptop says that is outdated.

Comment: (In particular, see point 9 about fonts).

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Is there any more beautiful symbol for natural numbers set depictable by Mathjax?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

One way is to use `\mathbb{N}`. This produces:

$$\mathbb{N}$$

This is very common.

Comment: Any other alternative?

Comment: Do you know why \Natural or \mathds{N} don't work?  The latter was offered by Detexify!

Comment: @HamidRezaEbrahimi: I don't know. I have never seen \Natural used before.

Comment: Where can I find the most comprehensive Mathjax documentation?

Comment: @HamidRezaEbrahimi: Probably here: https://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/

Comment: Thank you so much Thomas

Comment: @HamidRezaEbrahimi: you are welcome.

Comment: Probably `\Natural` and `\mathds` are part of some macro package, so you need to include that package to use them...